# Python locate words in nltk.tree

Tags: python, nltk, chunking

I am trying to build a nltk to get the context of words. I have two sentences

```
sentences=pd.DataFrame({"sentence": ["The weather was good so I went swimming", "Because of the good food we took desert"]})
```

I would like to find out, what the word "good" refers to. My idea is to chunk the sentences (code from tutorial [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dongqing-chunking.pdf)) and then see if the word "good" and a noun are in the same node. If not, it refers to a noun before or after that.

First I build the Chunker as in the tutorial

```
from nltk.corpus import conll2000
test_sents = conll2000.chunked_sents('test.txt', chunk_types=['NP'])
train_sents = conll2000.chunked_sents('train.txt', chunk_types=['NP'])

class ChunkParser(nltk.ChunkParserI):
    def __init__(self, train_sents):
        train_data = [[(t,c) for w,t,c in nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(sent)]
            for sent in train_sents]
        self.tagger = nltk.TrigramTagger(train_data)
    def parse(self, sentence):
        pos_tags = [pos for (word,pos) in sentence]
        tagged_pos_tags = self.tagger.tag(pos_tags)
        chunktags = [chunktag for (pos, chunktag) in tagged_pos_tags]
        conlltags = [(word, pos, chunktag) for ((word,pos),chunktag)
        in zip(sentence, chunktags)]
        return nltk.chunk.conlltags2tree(conlltags)
```

`NPChunker = ChunkParser(train_sents)`

Then, I apply this on my sentences:

```
sentence=sentences["sentence"][0]
tags=nltk.pos_tag(sentence.lower().split())
result = NPChunker.parse(tags)
print result
```

The result looks like this

```
(S
  (NP the/DT weather/NN)
  was/VBD
  (NP good/JJ)
  so/RB
  (NP i/JJ)
  went/VBD
  swimming/VBG)
```

Now I would like to "find" in which node the word "good" is. I have not really figured out a better way but counting the words in the nodes and in the leaves. The word "good" is word number 3 in the sentence.

```
stuctured_sentence=[]
for n in range(len(result)):
    stuctured_sentence.append(list(result[n]))

structure_length=[]
for n in result:
    if isinstance(n, nltk.tree.Tree):               
        if n.label() == 'NP':
            print n
            structure_length.append(len(n))
    else:
        print str(n) +"is a leaf"
        structure_length.append(1)
```

From summing up the number of words, I know where the word "good" is.

```
structure_frame=pd.DataFrame({"structure": stuctured_sentence, "length": structure_length})
structure_frame["cumsum"]=structure_frame["length"].cumsum()
```

Is there an easier way to determine the node or leaf of words and find out to which word "good" refers to?

Best Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easiest to find your word in a list of leaves. You can then translate the leaf index into a tree index, which is a path down the tree. To see what is grouped with `good`, go up one level and examine the subtree that this picks out.

First, find out the position of `good` in your flat sentence. (You could skip this if you still had the untagged sentence as a list of tokens.)

```
words = [ w for w, t in result.leaves() ]
```

Now we find the linear position of `good`, and translate into a tree path:

```
>>> position = words.index("good")
>>> treeposition = result.leaf_treeposition(position)
>>> print(treeposition)
(2, 0)
```

A "treeposition" is a path down the tree, expressed as a tuple. (NLTK trees can be indexed with tuples as well as integers.) To see the sisters of `good`, stop one step before you get to the end of the path.

```
>>> print(result[ treeposition[:-1] ])
Tree('NP', [('good', 'JJ')])
```

There you are. A subtree with one leaf, the pair `(good, JJ)`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out.